# how to check if a word is repeated in string php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a database that have multiple fields. i've to display one of its field in  in html table. i can do it easily. but the problem is that the field i want to show may contain repeated words in a row. for eg

- john;mike;john
- john
- mike;mike;mike

now what i want to do is that i have to trim repeated words i.e if a word is more than once in a row so it should be displayed only once. e.g above will be

- john;mike
- john
- mike

i.e i don't want to show repetition when displaying record in html table. i want to make it dynamic i.e not just for 5 to 6 word. but to condemn repetition even if there thousands of records.

considering whole value of a row as a string how could i remove this using php ..

Thanks for your support in advance..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: step 1 normalise the db

Comment: "UD;RUP" is one word ?

Comment: UD is seperate word and RUP is seperate word...

Comment: but you dont separate those two in your above example

Comment: Let me edit the question. i've made a mistake ... Just 2 min.. let me edit it

Comment: done editing. check my question now ... Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$variable="mike;john;mike";

$each=explode(';',$variable);
//print_r($each);
$new=array_unique($each);

echo implode(';',$new); //mike;john
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll treat each line or row as a sentence you can split on the separator, the semicolon in your examples. So if "UD;RUP;UD;UD" is a line you do something like:

```
line = "UD;RUP;UD;UD";
lineArray = new Array();
lineArray=line.split(";");
```

Then you want to create a new array that will hold the unique values you parse from your string:

```
newArray = new Array();
```

Now you iterate over the first array and see if you already have it stored. If you don't, store it by pushing to your new array:

```
for(i=0;i<lineArray .length;i++)
{
    if((i==lineArray .indexOf(lineArray [i]))||(lineArray .indexOf(arr[i])==lineArray .lastIndexOf(arr[i])))
        newArray.push(lineArray [i]);   
}
```

And finally join the newArray elements:

```
newArray.join(";");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
 <?php

  $consulta=Array('azul,azul,verde,amarillo','verde','azul,verde','azul');

  $arrall=Array();

  foreach ($consulta as $value) {

     $arrnew= explode(",", $value);
     if(count($arrnew!=0)){

        foreach ($arrnew as $value) {
            array_push($arrall, $value);
         }
      }

  }

  $result = array_unique($arrall);
```

Comment: did not test this did you.

Comment: ok it works now, crazy overkill but it 'works'

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the key is to create a unique index for each record.

```php
<?php
    $records = array(
        'john;mike;john',
        'john',
        'mike;sally;mike;mike'
    );

    foreach($records as $index => $record) {
        $records[$index] = implode(';',array_unique(explode(';',$record)));
    }
    print_r($records);
?>
```

This is in plain JavaScript to show the concept

```js
var records = [
    'john;mike;john',
    'john',
    'mike;sally;mike;mike'
]

var tuple;
for(var r in records) { 
    var tuple = records[r].split(';');
    var index = {};
    for(var t in tuple) {
        index[tuple[t]] = true;
    }
    records[r] = Object.keys(index).join(';');
}

console.log(records);
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  /**
  * @param array|string $values
  * @param string $delimiter
  *
  * @return bool|string
  */
  function filterValues($values = array(), $delimiter = ';') {
        if(is_string($values) && $values) {
            $explodedValues = explode($delimiter, $values);

            return implode($delimiter, array_unique($explodedValues));
        } else if(is_array($values) && $values) {
            return implode($delimiter, array_unique($values));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $string= 'mike;bike;mike';
    $array = array('mike', 'bike', 'mike');

    echo filterValues($string);

    echo filterValues($array);
```